# Spring-amqp RabbitMQ - no exchange 'myexchange' in vhost '/' ERROR

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I know this question has been asked before but I couldnot find any suitable solution to my problem, hence posting it again.

I am trying to write a rabbitmq producer using spring-amqp to publish my messages on direct queue. Since its a producer application, my exchange and queue have to be created. Also I am not defining any listener bean as I do not need it at the producer end.
Below is my ***rabbitmq-config.xml***:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit
http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<!-- Spring AMQP Admin -->
<rabbit:admin id="amqpAdmin"
    connection-factory="rabbitmqConnectionFactory"
    auto-startup="true" />

<!-- Spring AMQP Template -->
<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate"
    connection-factory="rabbitmqConnectionFactory"
    routing-key="my.key" exchange="my.exchange" 
    channel-transacted="true"/>

<!-- Connection Factory -->
<rabbit:connection-factory id="rabbitmqConnectionFactory"
    host="${rabbitmq.host:localhost}" 
    port="${rabbitmq.port:5672}" 
    username="${rabbitmq.username}"
    password="${rabbitmq.password}" 
    virtual-host="${rabbitmq.vhost:/}"
    cache-mode="CONNECTION" 
    channel-cache-size="${rabbitmq.channel-cache-size:25}" />

<!-- Queue and Exchange -->
<rabbit:queue id="my.queue" durable="false"
    auto-declare="true" auto-delete="true" />

<rabbit:direct-exchange name="my.exchange" durable="false"
    auto-declare="true" auto-delete="true" declared-by="amqpAdmin">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="my.queue" key="my.key"/>
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:direct-exchange>
</beans>
```

I just have a simple producer class, which uses the above *amqpTemplate* to send a message. 
But when I try running my producer application, all I get is:
 **no exchange 'my.exchange' in vhost '/' ERROR**

> ```
> ERROR CachingConnectionFactory:1089 - Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'my.exchange' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40)
> DEBUG CachingConnectionFactory:842 - Detected closed channel on exception.  Re-initializing: AMQChannel(amqp://s3conn@127.0.0.1:5672/,1)
> DEBUG RabbitResourceHolder:189 - Rolling back messages to channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://s3conn@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), conn: Proxy@17a7f733 Dedicated Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@2118cddf [delegate=amqp://s3conn@127.0.0.1:5672/]
> TRACE CachingConnectionFactory:906 - Returning cached Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://s3conn@127.0.0.1:5672/,1)
> Exception in thread "main"
> DEBUG CachingConnectionFactory:1008 - Returning connection 'Proxy@17a7f733 Dedicated Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@2118cddf [delegate=amqp://s3conn@127.0.0.1:5672/]' to cache
> org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
>     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitUtils.commitIfNecessary(RabbitUtils.java:105)
>     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1354)
>     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate$3.doInRabbit(RabbitTemplate.java:623)
>     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1298)
>     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1271)
>     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:619)
>     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:613)
>     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:603)
>     at com.symantec.spe.cloud.amqpclient.JsonMessagePublisherImpl.sendMessage(JsonMessagePublisherImpl.java:53)
>     at com.symantec.spe.cloud.amqpclient.test.TestProducer.main(TestProducer.java:50)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException
>     at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:106)
>     at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:102)
>     at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:124)
>     at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.txCommit(ChannelN.java:1163)
>     at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.txCommit(ChannelN.java:61)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:835)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.txCommit(Unknown Source)
>     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitUtils.commitIfNecessary(RabbitUtils.java:103)
>     ... 9 more
> Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchang
> e 'my.exchange' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40)
>     at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67)
>     at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:33)
>     at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:361)
>     at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:226)
>     at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:118)
>     ... 18 more
> Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchang
> e 'my.exchange' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40)
>     at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:484)
>     at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:321)
>     at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:144)
>     at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:91)
>     at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:554)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> ```

Any help on this would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
cache-mode="CONNECTION"
```

See [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#automatic-declaration):

> Automatic declaration is only performed when the `CachingConnectionFactory` cache mode is `CHANNEL` (the default). This limitation exists because exlusive and auto-delete queues are bound to the connection.

(Oops! Typo is there. Will fix soon :-) )

Comment: Also, even with CHANNEL cache mode, since both the exchange and queue are auto-delete, if the consumer starts and stops (or somehow loses its connection) while the producer is still running, the queue and exchange will be deleted; the producer will have no knowledge of that and won't re-declare in that case.

Comment: @Artem Bilan, thanks for your help. It solved my problem. I changed the cache-mode to CHANNEL and since I wanted durable and non-exclusive queues, I set those fields appropriately.

Comment: @GaryRussell, would this be true for non-exclusive queues as well? Thanks.

Comment: `exclusive` is irrelevant - `auto-delete` queues are deleted by rabbit when the consumer no longer consumes from them. They will exist after declaration until a consumer starts consuming, and then stops after which they are deleted. `auto-delete` exchanges are deleted when the last bound queue is deleted. Read the RabbitMQ documentation to get a full understanding of these semantics.

Comment: BTW, cache mode CONNECTION is rarely needed. A single connection is generally recommended.

Comment: @GaryRussell, thanks a lot for your input, I will also go through the docs.